# There are no entities matching. BaseFieldDefinition entity reference error for taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

My Code looks like this:

```
$fields['color'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Color'))
  ->setDescription(t('The color of the fruit.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['Color' => 'Color']])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'author',
    'weight' => -3,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => [
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => 60,
      'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ],
    'weight' => -3,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I have a vocabulary with the name : 'Color' 
I have 3 terms in it : 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'

The error I'm getting is this :

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Just Change the `Color` to `color` in  `['target_bundles' => ['Color' => 'Color']])` if you create a vocabulary caller `Color` the machine name will be `color` Not `Color` .

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Color** to **color** in `['target_bundles' => ['Color' => 'Color']])` if you create a vocabulary caller **Color** the machine name will be **color** Not **Color** So try with:

```
$fields['color'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Color'))
      ->setDescription(t('The color of the fruit.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
      // Target is color not Color.
      ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['color' => 'Color']])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label'  => 'above',
        'type'   => 'author',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type'     => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'settings' => [
          'match_operator'    => 'CONTAINS',
          'size'              => 60,
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder'       => '',
        ],
        'weight'   => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My machine name is: fruits_color. So should I change it to `['fruits_color' => 'Color']`  ?

Comment: welcome, yes you should change  it to `['fruits_color' => 'Color']`

Comment: Now, getting a different error, 'taste' column unknown. not found in field list. sorry but cant understand this error

Comment: so you should debug this error not from this code there is no `taste` field as i can see

Comment: Okay, Thankyou sir.